# How to compare unix timestamp to ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord, time, activesupport

I have a unix timestamp integer of `1550814673` and I want to compare it to:

```rb
Record.first.created_at
=> Fri, 22 Feb 2019 05:51:13 UTC +00:00
Record.first.created_at.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

I've tried turning the integer into datetime with this:

```
Time.at(1550814673).utc.to_datetime
=> Fri, 22 Feb 2019 05:51:13 +0000
```

But that is not quite the same and will not compare truthfully with a `==` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new [`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) instance from a timestamp with `Time.zone.at`:

```
irb(main):015:0> Time.zone.at(0)
=> Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
irb(main):019:0> Time.zone.at(0).class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

This also goes for the other factory methods like `now`, `local` and `parse`.

You can also convert a Time or DateTime instance with `#in_time_zone`.

```
irb(main):014:0> Time.at(0).in_time_zone
=> Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: However `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instances do actually equate with Time instances if the timezone is the same. For example `Time.zone.at(1550814673) == Time.at(1550814673)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `to_i` on a time, and it should give you something that you could use

```rb
date = Date.today
=> Tue, 14 May 2019
date.to_time.to_i
=> 1557784800
Time.at(1557784800)
=> 2019-05-14 00:00:00 +0200
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime` instead!

```
DateTime.strptime("1318996912",'%s')

=> Wed, 19 Oct 2011 04:01:52 +0000
```

Should return something easy to digest, and you can then easily do this:

```
DateTime.parse("#{Record.first.created_at}") == DateTime.strptime("1318996912",'%s')

=> true
```

`DateTime.parse` will automatically convert the `TimeWithZone` string to a `DateTime` object for easy comparison.